# In Perl, how can I test if a string is a palindrome?

Tags: perl

I'm attempting to write a Perl program to determine if a 7 character user input is a palindrome.

Without using any array, string, or reverse functions.

Desired output:

```
    Enter in a 7 character item: 1111111
    PALINDROME!
```

Or

```
    Enter in a 7 character item: 1234567
    NOT A PALINDROME!
```

This is what I have so far:

```
print "Enter in a 7 character item: \n";
my ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g);
chomp ($a=<>); chomp ($b=<>); chomp ($c=<>); chomp ($d=<>);
chomp ($e=<>); chomp ($f=<>); chomp ($g=<>);
if ($a~~$g && $b~~$g && $c~~$e){
    print "PALINDROME!\n";
}
else{
    print "NOT A PALINDROME! \n";
}
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me this result:

```
    Enter in a 7 character item:
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    PALINDROME!
```

If anyone has suggestions, that would be greatly appreciated.

I look forward to hearing your input. Thank you!

Comment: Without reverse--probably doable. Without arrays--well, maybe some really black regex magic could help. But hey, *without strings*? Are we still talking about Perl?

Comment: BTW from the title I thought you want **the code** itself to be palindrome... That would be hell of a challenge!

Comment: Palindromic palindrome checker (code game): http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/palindromic-palindrome-checker

Answer (score 7):

That looks correct to me, after all `1111111` is a palindrome!

However, the smart match operator isn't a very useful thing, and you want to test for string equality here, so use `eq` instead of `~~`.

Even better I would suggest that you allow the user to enter an entire string, so

```
chomp(my $str = <>);

if ( $str eq reverse($str) ) {
     print "PALINDROME!\n";
}
else {
     print "NOT A PALINDROME! \n";
}
```

Comment: Nice, as a one-liner: `perl -lnE 'say if $_ eq reverse()' /usr/share/dict/brazilian`

Answer (score 5):

Without using `reverse`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($word) = @ARGV;

my @chars = split //, $word;
my $palindrome = 1;
for (0..@chars/2-1) {
   $palindrome = $chars[$_] eq $chars[-($_+1)]
      or last;
}

print "$word ".($palindrome ? "is" : "isn't")." a palindrome\n";
```

Usage:

```
script word
```

Answer (score 1):

no reverse used, but regex (and recursion).

```
 sub palyndromeP{
     my $s=shift;
     if (length($s)<2) {return 1}        
     if ($s !~ /^(.)(.*)\1$/) {return 0}
     return palyndromeP($2);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing

$b~~$g to $b~~$f might also help .